# Golang websocket's SetWriteDeadline function

Tags: go, websocket, timeout

Go's websockets have a **SetWriteDeadline()** function to set the connection's network write deadline. Do I need to set it before every data sending or it can be done just once when the connection is created?

Comment: which websocket , `golang.org/x/net/websocket`  or  `github.com/gorilla/websocket`?

Comment: @zzn ofc `golang.org/x/net/websocket`,  github.com/gorilla/websocket = garbage.

Comment: @zzn, yes, golang.org's library. Gorilla's is useful, but slow

Answer (score 1):

For it to be useful at all, set it every time.  Note that it takes a `time.Time`, not a `time.Duration`:

```golang
SetWriteDeadline(t time.Time) error
```

Answer (score -4):

Set it **once**.

PS I checked it myself, it's a simple code.

Comment: Please provide some more details.

Comment: This reply is wrong. The deadlines are set as absolute times, so need to be extended each time there's a new operation, unless you're happy to work within a timelimit based on the first operation.